# CoreData RelationShips Setting RelationShip Types

Tags: ios, core-data

I Just Tried CoreData Relation Ships
It Works Fine But

Two Entities Are Connected So , If am deleting data from one entity it should reflect the connect entity what should i do ?

code Givn below

```
    AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
Person *per = [NSEntityDescription
               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:context];
per.name = @"Test Name";
per.age=@"age";
Medicine *med = [NSEntityDescription
                 insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Medicine"
                                        inManagedObjectContext:context];
med.name= @"paracetmol";
per.meddet = med;
med.patdet = per;
NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}else{
    NSLog(@"ok");
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person"
                                          inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (Person *info in fetchedObjects) {
    NSLog(@"Name: %@", info.name);
     NSLog(@"%@",info.meddet.name);
}
```

Comment: did you mean, if you deleted the person object, the connected med object also gets deleted? if so, you could set the relationship from the person to med with a deleteRule Cascade

Comment: yap got it thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the relationship from the person to med with a deleteRule Cascade